Ag-grid group column
I am using ag-grid in my project and to pass data from that I'm using list component which will receive data from SQL.
The columns to display are dynamic columns. It will be based on the range values we have selected.How the data comes from SQL when we select range as 2 is:
D1,D2,A1,A2,P1,P2,W1,W2,M1,M2
How it displays in grid is:
|D1|D2|A1|A2|P1|P2|W1|W2|M1|M2
Now I want the grid to have column with header as A1 and below that I want to have sub columns with  heardes as A1,P1,W1
|  A1    |
|A1|P1|W1|
So can someone help me with how can I achieve this??I am getting all these columns as a result through query I just want to reassign these columns like column starts with A columns should become header and the same A columns,P col,W col and M col should be child for that A related columns.
Written in description

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
